# ADF Mapping Data Flow - Dirty / Label Replacement / Sink cache and derived column

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am trying to build a ADF mapping data flow for generic adding Label - it's purpose is to see a value in a particular column and replace it with a label . I already have my dataset that looks like this (Table B):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr4oX.png)

The goal is to replace the values with the label ones. Since my label dataset mapping file is in a Cached Sink (Table B),I thought that I could use a Derived Column Activity, along with Cached Lookups to find the clean value, given the current Column Name and current value (dirty) as keys. I did a rule-based mapping expression to get just the columns that needed cleaning:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvHlw.png)

I tested the derived column transformation using: Each column that matches:libCached#lookup(name).Column_Name

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYXEA.png)

This part allow me to  distinct column names that need to be replaced by label and that's working fine.

I need help to make the replacement I tried several formulas it still doesn't work, I don't know if it's achievable or not ??

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To replace the actual values in the derived column, you'll need to use the lookup formula using the key that you've set in the cached sink so that ADF can match on that value. In the screenshot you have, it only shows that you checking for null and are not actually returning the lookup value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but I can't manage to link two elements of the table (column_Name and Option_LBL) for example that I am asked to replace with the labels: toString(libCached#lookup(toString($$)).Option_LBL) , it doesn't recognize option_LBL as it's not Key Columns
thank you in advance for your help

Comment: If you use #output instead, then you won't need to match on a key